# Books suggestions on the fundamental of geometry

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation

I want to self-study geometry for interest. What I want to study is closed to the fundamental appeal, not problem-solving, not differential geometry. But I found that there were many of books on geometry. And it is difficult for a beginner like me to figure out which books are the ones I need.

I want to learn the axiomatic/synthetic, ancient/modern  fundamentals of geometry, such like what is "point", "segment", "directed segment", "Euclidean vector", "plane", "congruence", "affine space", etc; and what is the modern way of defining and treating these concepts? If there's a book compare those difference is also what I want. I guess this kind of books should be of graduate level right? I've studied analysis and linear algebra, so a book uses plenty of terminology of these subject is OK for me!

Comment: I would recommend Hartshorne's *Euclid and beyond* for a modern treatment with some context of the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two texts on Geometry which base the treatment on Linear Algebra:

Audin -- Geometry (2003)

Gruenberg & Weir -- Linear Geometry, 2nd Ed (1977)

Here's one that does Geometry based on a combination of analytic tools$\,-\,$coordinates, Calculus, as well as lots of Linear Algebra:

Brannan & others -- Geometry, 2nd Ed (2012)

Comment: Thanks. Did Audin's Geometry briefly mention why he adopt the linear algebra approach but not the others? Or did he explain at first or at end the benefit of such approach?

Comment: From Audin's introduction: "This is a book written for students who have been taught a small amount of geometry at secondary school and some linear algebra at university. ... Two directing ideas. The first idea is to give a rigorous exposition, based on the definition of an affine space via linear algebra, but not hesitating to be elementary and down-to-earth. I have tried both to explain that linear algebra is useful for elementary geometry ... and to show “genuine” geometry: triangles, spheres, polyhedra, angles
at the circumference, inversions, parabolas. . ."